# Query a many-to-many relation using Gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a `Movie` model that has a lot of many-to-many relations defined in Gorm. Now I have to create an API to query all the movies that have an ID in those relations.

Let's break it into small pieces:

Movie's model:

```
type Movie struct {
    gorm.Model
    TitleID           string     `gorm:"size:50;not null" json:"title_id"`
    OriginalName      string     `gorm:"size:250;not null" json:"original_name"`
    Categories        []Category `gorm:"null;many2many:movie_categories;" json:"categories"`
    Types             []Type     `gorm:"null;many2many:movie_types;" json:"types"`
    Directors         []Cast     `gorm:"null;many2many:movie_directors;" json:"directors"`
    Writers           []Cast     `gorm:"null;many2many:movie_writers;" json:"writers"`
}
```

My Query function:

```
func (u *Movie) FindMoviesByDirectors(db *gorm.DB, directors string) (*[]Movie, error) {
    var err error
    movies := []Movie{}
    err = db.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true).Where("directors = ?", directors).Find(&movies).Error
    if err != nil {
        return &[]Movie{}, err
    }
    return &movies, err
}
```

1. How can I query movies with an ID from the relation? (in my case, querying all the movies that have ID `1` as a `director`.)
2. How can I extend it to query movies with multiple IDs and multiple relations? (for example, querying all the movies which have a `[1,2]` IDs for `directors` and `[3,4]` for the `types`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Question Responses

1. You could query the foreign key reference id in the many-to-many relation referenced (see samples below)
2. You could use the `IN` operator to query multiple values at once. `gorm` supports this see https://gorm.io/docs/query.html

### Possible Solutions

For this, your raw sql could look like :

```sql
SELECT 
    M.* 
FROM
    movies M
LEFT JOIN movie_categories MC on MC.movie_id = M.id
LEFT JOIN movie_types MT on MT.movie_id = M.id
LEFT JOIN movie_directors MD on MD.movie_id = M.id
LEFT JOIN movie_writers MW on MW.movie_id = M.id
WHERE
  MC.category_id IN (?) OR
  MT.type_id IN (?) OR
  MD.director_id IN (?) OR
  MW.writer_id IN (?)
```

NB. I've used Left join in the event that a movie has no records in a particular relation. The where condition will ensure that desired records are returned. Furthermore the `OR` implies that any of these criteria can be met. If you would like all these criteria to be met you may use `AND` instead of `OR`.

#### Assumptions for possible solutions below

Assuming that

1. the sql above was stored in a variable `sql`
2. the desired category ids where stored in a an array `categories` eg. `[]int64{1,2,3}`
3. the desired type ids where stored in a an array `types` eg. `[]int64{1,2,3}`
4. the desired director ids where stored in a an array `directors` eg. `[]int64{1,2,3}`
5. the desired writer ids where stored in a an array `writers` eg. `[]int64{1,2,3}`

You may modify your function signature as necessary to accept these parameters as desired.

#### Possible Solution 1

`Gorm` allows you to use [raw-sql](https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html)

Eg.

```golang
result := db.Raw(sql,categories,types,directors,writers).Scan(&movies)
err := result.Error
```

#### Possible Solution 2

`Gorm` allows you to build your own [`joins`](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Joins) using their [query builder](https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html) which may be useful if you would like to optimize the queries run on the db. For example, if your `directors` array is empty but `categories` is not, you could only query the `categories` relations. Moreover, you could fine tune your query with the builder object

Eg.

```golang
var query = db.Table("movies") //or you could use db.Model(&Movie{})

query = query.Select("movies.*")

// begin querying relations
if( len(categories)>0 ){
    query = query.Joins("LEFT JOIN movie_categories on movie_categories.movie_id = movies.id");
}

if( len(categories)>0 ){
    query = query.Where("movie_categories.category_id IN (?)",categories);
}
//end querying relations
//you could repeat this for each relation

//With the Gorm query builder object store in query you can make other modifications before executing the query

result := query.Scan(&movies)
err := result.Error
```

### Additional Considerations

If you are interested in querying all movies based on the category name, you could use the same approach through `joins` to write your query.

### References/ Resources

Gorm `Where In` - https://gorm.io/docs/query.html

Gorm SQL Builder - https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have an error when running possible solution 2, 

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1" at character 138`
`pq: syntax error at or near "$1" `

Comment: it creates this query: `STATEMENT:  SELECT movies.* FROM "movies" LEFT JOIN movie_categories on movie_categories.movie_id = movies.id WHERE (movie_categories.category_id IN $1)`

Comment: @Morteza I've amended it to include `query = query.Where("movie_categories.category_id IN (?)",categories);` with brackets